# Print a page without forms' urls in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, printing

Rails put the url of the form aside of the link to submit it, when printing. Like this: http://d.pr/i/UCBP

Anyone help me to remove this? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this in 2 ways:

1) you can use **css styles** for media screen print to hide those links while in print mode http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/:

```
 @media print {
   .your-class {
      visibility: none;
   }
 }
```

2) you can use a gem like **wicked_pdf** (https://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf) and generate your own views for pdf using a link on your page that will say like: "Print version"

```
class ThingsController < ApplicationController
  def show
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.pdf do
        render :pdf => "file_name"
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks @rmagnum2002. But where I put the "your-class" in my markup?

Comment: in css, read the tutorial that I put a link for, and fonr more about media print, it's not that hard.

Comment: but I suggest you to go with the custom pdf template with wicked_pdf, it is easy to set up and you customize your page as you want. I used it when I just started to learn rails so this is not hard at all.

Comment: I see. I don't understand where put the class 'cause the links' url are hidden, only appear in printing. Thanks :)